# C# , wsdl proxy classes , how to use it?

Tags: c#, service, proxy, wsdl

I have a wsdl and xsd files, and with wsdl.exe utility i generate proxy classes, but in project i have not any service reference, haow can use it with c#?

Answer (score 0):

wsdl.exe will generate a `.cs` file containing the proxy classes. You need to copy and include this file to your project (Add existing file ...).

And if you want to use a WCF client you should use [**svcutil.exe**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to generate your client proxy, not `wsdl.exe`. The Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio internally uses svcutil.exe. The Add Web Reference dialog uses wsdl.exe.

Comment: Yes, i do it, then?      AuthenticationWSBinding d=new AuthenticationWSBinding();

            d.authenticate();   But it does not work, i have not any service reference , config , endpoint...

Comment: @ArmenKhachatryan, then you instantiate the client proxy class contained in this file and invoke the methods. wsdl.exe does not use any endpoints and bindings. That's WCF. If you want to use a WCF client you need to use **svcutil.exe** to generate your client proxy, not wsdl.exe. I have updated my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: svcutil.exe generates  endpoints and bindings? i want to have a service config file! because then i need to add informaton about certificate.

Comment: With visual studio i can not add service reference and web service reference , in both case it returns error, is there any other method to make connfig file? with wdsl or svcutil ?

Comment: @ArmenKhachatryan, svcutil.exe also generates an app.config file containing the WCF service endpoint configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consume the web service use `wsdl.exe` to generate the proxy class and after adding that class in your project you can use the service and their methods. And if you have a wcf service which you want to consume you will have to use `svcutil.exe` to generate the proxy class. you need not to create the metadata(wsdl,xsd etc.) of the service.